# How to transfer text box from page to another page

Tags: php, input, textbox

I am new to php and I need some help.

I have two sites. And I want to display text box from my edit.php on index.php.

```
        <form method="post">
        <textarea name="content" cols="40" rows="5">
        Enter your comments here...
        </textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
          <?php
       $content = $_POST["content"];?>
```

How do I transfer variable $content to my index page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your comments.  (Don't down rank me... his original question was not precise).

```
// on your edit page
<form method="post">
<textarea name="content"></textarea>
<input type="submit" />
</form>

// when you submit your edit page
$filename = '/mytextarea.txt';
$content = file_put_contents( $filename, $_POST['content'] );   

// on your index page
$filename = '/mytextarea.txt';
$content = file_get_contents($filename);

if( ! empty( $content ) ){
    echo '<div>'.$content.'</div>'; 
}
```

Comment: tnxxxx this is the solution i was asking. Thx 1 more time!

Answer (score 1):

From edit you want to make sure your action points to index.php

edit.php

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <textarea name="myTextBox" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In index.php, you can access the variable with $_POST["myTextBox"], this can be outputted as text or as a value in the example below.  Be sure to use htmlentities when including the value back with a form field, this will prevent "injection hacking".
index.php

```
<?php echo $_POST["myTextBox"] ?>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <textarea name="myTextBox" cols="40" rows="5"><?php echo htmlentities($_POST["myTextBox"]); ?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, just set the action on the form to the page you want it to post to - example:

Random Page:

```
    <form method="post" action="/index.php">
    <textarea name="content" cols="40" rows="5">
    Enter your comments here...
    </textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Index.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['content']) && !empty($_POST['content'])){
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['content']);
}
```

At least I think this is what you are asking?

If you are echoing a random textbox to a page, make sure to sanitize it using `htmlspecialchars()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to action your form to your index.php :

```
<form method="post" action="/index.php">
</form>
```

With that, once you submit your form, your page index.php will be loaded, with values of your form in $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

```
// on your edit page
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<textarea name="content"></textarea>
<input type="submit" />
</form>

// on your index page
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ){ // This will prevent the textarea from
     // being shown unless some form posted to this page
    echo '<form method="post">
    <textarea name="content">'.$_POST['content'].'</textarea>
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>';
     // If it's not set or it's empty, then it just won't show anything....
     // you don't need to check for that unless you want to set a value when it is empty
}
```

Comment: I need to put text from edit page to a div in my index page... So it should look like a normal text on a index page

Comment: You just encapsulate $_POST['content'] with <div> instead of <textarea>

Answer (score 0):

Just change your form to post to the second site instead of to itself, then echo the $_POST['content'] on your index.php page

**www.firstsite.com/edit.php**

```
<form action="www.secondsite.com/index.php" method="post">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <textarea name="content" cols="40" rows="5">Enter your comments here...</textarea>
    </li>
    <li class="submit">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

**www.secondsite.com/index.php**

```
<?php echo $_POST['content']; ?>
```

Comment: i need to se content that is typed in edit.php when i connect directily on index.php.Even if i didnt put some content this session

Comment: In that case you would have to save the results of the form post to a database or text file, then pull that saved data into your index.php